# How to send poll question in email and get answer from other in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How to send poll question in email and get answer from other in outlook 2007?

I want to make poll like on this page

http://css-tricks.com/polls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP100804251033.aspx

good luck

Comment: have u seen link of my question

Comment: try this: http://mypollcreator.com/